# Confusion matrix problem; Result show only 0 and 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, confusion-matrix

I have the same problem, always the same. When I run a confusion matrix its results display only 0s &  1s. It is not suppose to go like this, here's the problem.

[image: Image of the problem.]

It suppose to go between 0 and 20 but it's not. What I done wrong? and how can I fix this.

Here's the code I used

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

imagegen = ImageDataGenerator()

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Problem\New_one\Testing_Data",
                                                    class_mode="categorical",
                                                    shuffle=False,
                                                    batch_size=3,
                                                    target_size=(200, 200))

model = keras.models.load_model(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Problem\New_one\InceptionV3.h5")

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'y_Actual': ["Lablae", "Long", "Maejam(Ceiyng-saen-hnoy)","Maejam(Ceiyng-saen-luang)","Maejam(Hong-pi)","Maejam(Hong-poi)","Maejam(Kan-seiyn-sam)",
                    "Maejam(Kom-rup-nk)","Maejam(Kom-whua-mon-nai-nk-non)","Maejam(Kud-kho-bed)","Maejam(La-kon-klang)","Maejam(La-kon-luang)",
                    "Maejam(La-kon-noy)","Maejam(Lay-kan-sam-aew)","Maejam(Nak-kum)","Maejam(Nk-kum)","Maejam(Nok-nk-kum)","Maejan(Khan-aew-u)",
                    "Muang-nan","Sri-sat-shanalai"],
        'y_Predicted': ["Lablae", "Long", "Maejam(Ceiyng-saen-hnoy)","Maejam(Ceiyng-saen-luang)","Maejam(Hong-pi)","Maejam(Hong-poi)","Maejam(Kan-seiyn-sam)",
                    "Maejam(Kom-rup-nk)","Maejam(Kom-whua-mon-nai-nk-non)","Maejam(Kud-kho-bed)","Maejam(La-kon-klang)","Maejam(La-kon-luang)",
                    "Maejam(La-kon-noy)","Maejam(Lay-kan-sam-aew)","Maejam(Nak-kum)","Maejam(Nk-kum)","Maejam(Nok-nk-kum)","Maejan(Khan-aew-u)",
                    "Muang-nan","Sri-sat-shanalai"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['y_Actual','y_Predicted'])
confusion_matrix = pd.crosstab(df['y_Actual'], df['y_Predicted'], rownames=['Actual'], colnames=['Predicted'], margins = True)

sn.heatmap(confusion_matrix, annot=True)
plt.show()
```

I'll admit here. I'm not good on programming and I'll never be. This is the only problem I have, and I need to fix it so I can progress.

P.S. I'm not good in writing english, so I might made some mistake here. If I did, then I apologise.

Comment: It shows 20 too, in the right bottom corner. In fact, the confusion matrix is correct. `y_Actual[0] == y_Predicted[0] == "Lablae"`, so 1 is added to intersection of "Lablae" and "Lablae". The similar logic for all other values, because `y_Actual` and `y_Predicted` contain the same data.

Comment: The issue seems to be that you don't actually use your model. 'y_Predicted' should be the output of your model but it is just literally the same as 'y_Actual'.

Comment: To khituras : how can I do that, blindly put [model] to [y.Predicted] won't going to do, right? Is there's a method to do that?

Comment: Because you blidly put it in, it got [All arrays must be of the same length]. So this won't do. How Can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your predictions match the true labels. Thus, you perform a perfect classification with 100 % accuracy.

Make sure to obtain the predictions from `model` i.e., `model.predict()`, which is currently not used. Exclude the subtotals from crosstab with `margins=False`, otherweise you include the subtotals in the confusion matrix.

Here is an example, for a less ideal classification with one edited value (last in dict) to demonstrate the concept:

```py
import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    "y_Actual": [
        "Lablae",
        "Long",
        "Maejam(Ceiyng-saen-hnoy)",
        "Maejam(Ceiyng-saen-luang)",
        "Maejam(Hong-pi)",
        "Maejam(Hong-poi)",
        "Maejam(Kan-seiyn-sam)",
        "Maejam(Kom-rup-nk)",
        "Maejam(Kom-whua-mon-nai-nk-non)",
        "Maejam(Kud-kho-bed)",
        "Maejam(La-kon-klang)",
        "Maejam(La-kon-luang)",
        "Maejam(La-kon-noy)",
        "Maejam(Lay-kan-sam-aew)",
        "Maejam(Nak-kum)",
        "Maejam(Nk-kum)",
        "Maejam(Nok-nk-kum)",
        "Maejan(Khan-aew-u)",
        "Muang-nan",
        "Sri-sat-shanalai",
    ],
    "y_Predicted": [
        "Lablae",
        "Long",
        "Maejam(Ceiyng-saen-hnoy)",
        "Maejam(Ceiyng-saen-luang)",
        "Maejam(Hong-pi)",
        "Maejam(Hong-poi)",
        "Maejam(Kan-seiyn-sam)",
        "Maejam(Kom-rup-nk)",
        "Maejam(Kom-whua-mon-nai-nk-non)",
        "Maejam(Kud-kho-bed)",
        "Maejam(La-kon-klang)",
        "Maejam(La-kon-luang)",
        "Maejam(La-kon-noy)",
        "Maejam(Lay-kan-sam-aew)",
        "Maejam(Nak-kum)",
        "Maejam(Nk-kum)",
        "Maejam(Nok-nk-kum)",
        "Maejan(Khan-aew-u)",
        "Sri-sat-shanalai",
        "Sri-sat-shanalai",
    ],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["y_Actual", "y_Predicted"])
confusion_matrix = pd.crosstab(
    df["y_Actual"],
    df["y_Predicted"],
    rownames=["Actual"],
    colnames=["Predicted"],
    margins=False,
)

sn.heatmap(confusion_matrix, annot=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: possible output]